# How to get the current path using another file in Python

Tags: python, os.path

How can I get the current path using another file.

Example:
I have the folder structure below:

```
src 
  script.py
  configs
     initial_config.py
```

In my initial_config.py file I have the code below:

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print(path)

#The return of this print is /src/configs
```

In my script.py I'm trying to import the initial_config file and the return of the print I need it to be the script.py path.

```
from configs.initial_config import path
print(path)
#The return of this import is /src/configs
```

How can I return the /src/ path having the os.path function in other file in the simplest way possible?

Answer (score 0):

Turn your logic of finding the path into a function in `configs/initial_config.py`, then import it from `scripts.py`:

```
# configs/initial_config.py

import os

def find_path(file=__file__):
    return os.path.dirname(file)
```

```
# script.py

from configs.initial_config import find_path

print(find_path(__file__))
```